Newly provisioned samba PDC allows joining but no connection
I have provisioned a fresh new PDC on my new Raspberry Pi/ubuntu for the domain MYOFFICE.MYBUSINESS.CO.UK.  This is the most cost-effective solution for my purposes as a freelance developer.
I can join either a Windows 10 or Windows 11 machine to the domain MYOFFICE well enough, apparently, but when I try login things start to go wrong - the domain is 'not available' and I notice this :
 C:\> netdom verify orac

 The secure channel from ORAC to MYOFFICE
 is invalid.
 
 We can't sign you in with this credential because your domain isn't
 available. Make sure your device is connected to your organization's
 network and try again. If you previously signed in on this device with
 another credential, you can sign in with that credential.

When I spin up 'Active Directory Users and Computers' I can see the newly joined computers, my newly created users, and so on, so I know the domain exists, but that too has a tendency to report
The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

I also notice that, when joining, the domain 'MYOFFICE' is ok, but 'myoffice.mybusiness.co.uk' is unsuccessful.
Please, if anyone can provide some clues for me I would be most grateful; I am on about my 5th reinstall and this is becoming a problem. How can a domain be available and not available at the same time?

My hunch is that this is a DNS problem in that your domain-joined clients aren't configured to use the correct DNS server for the domain, or you don't have a DNS server setup and/or configured correctly for the domain.

I agree that seems likely but all my tests seem to check out : I can successfully nslookup myoffice, myoffice.mybusiness.co.uk and dc.myoffice.mybusiness.co.uk.  What else is there?

DNS for AD requires more than just the domain name, it makes a number of other records for each DC plus the domain.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/verify-srv-dns-records-have-been-created
That might not be your only problem. You need to do a deep dive into learning how AD and DNS work together, and if Samba complicates things.
